# How many ways can a woman polish her nails if she uses one of two colors on each nail?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

A woman is preparing to go to a party and would like to have her nails polished. Suppose she wants to use either the light pink or red nail polish on each nail, how many ways can shepolish her nails?

Note : We assume that she has ten fingers and all nails must be polished.

It's simple, but still I can't get it. I'm sorry if it's a little bit confusing.

This is my solution, but I don't know its correct or not.

Solution:  Let Red Polish = R and Light Pink Polish = P.

Consider all possible selections for ten fingers polished with red or light pink.

We have (10P,0R),(9P,1R),(8P,2R),(7P,3R),(6P,2R),(5P,5R),(4P,6R),(3P,7R),(2P,8R),(1P,9R),(0P,10R).

C(11,0)+C(10,1)+C(9,2)+C(8,3)+C(7,4)+C(6,5)=150 ways to polish her nails.

Is it correct?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit what you tried to solve it, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Comment: It is not connected to derangements. Just fingernails, or toenails too?

Comment: The person colours nails from left to right. There are $2$ choices of colour for the little finder on the left hand. For each choice, there are $2$ choices for the next finger. And so on.

Comment: Im sorry if my writing a little bit confusing. I need your help. This is my solution but I didnt know its correct or not. Solution: Let Red Polish = R and Light Pink Polish = P

consider all possible selections for ten finger polished with red or light pink. we have (10P,0R),(9P,1R),(8P,2R),(7P,3R),(6P,2R),(5P,5R),(4P,6R),(3P,7R),(2P,8R),(1P,9R),(0P,10R).

C(11,0)+C(10,1)+C(9,2)+C(8,3)+C(7,4)+C(6,5)=150 ways to polish her nails.

is it correct?

Answer (score 5):

$$2 \times 2 \times 2 \times \dotsb \times 2 = 2^{10} = 1024$$

or

$${10 \choose 0} + {10 \choose 1} + {10 \choose 2} + \dotsb + {10 \choose 10} = (1+1)^{10}$$

which is what you were trying to do when you said "(10P,0R),(9P,1R),(8P,2R),(7P,3R),(6P,2R),(5P,5R),(4P,6R),(3P,7R),(2P,8R),(1P,9R),(0P,10R)".

Answer (score 0):

What if I use Number of subsets theory..
Let number of nails to be 10 so the set will be set N ={f1 ,f2,f3,f4,.......,f10} , n=10

Now for PINK colour ways to choose any nails to be coloured can be = 2^n = 2^10 = 1024 subsets/ways

For RED colour would be the same :

2^10  = 1024

Therefore altogether will be 1024+1024 = 2048 ways ...

But i'm also not really sure on this solution .